# Different screen slide animations for ViewPager for different sliding directions

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I'm looking for a way how to implement different slide animations for `ViewPager` for different slide directions. Of course we can implement `ViewPager.PageTransformer` and set it for `ViewPager` instance, but it will be the same animation for right and left slide directions.

Currently I see only one way to implement what I want. We can extend standard `ViewPager` and override `onPageScrolled()` method, and customize animations inside this method through getting left and right views and setting transformation parameters for them. But may be somebody knows how to do that in simpler(another) way?